# Chrome. При переходе на вкладку белый экран и появление сайта

Tags: php, html, google-chrome

Сайт полностью загружен. Но когда я нахожусь в других вкладках, а потом перехожу обратно на вкладку с сайтом, то появляется белый экран и где-то через пол секунды появляется весь сайт. Но важно то, что сайт не перезагружается, то есть браузер будто "вспоминает", что было на вкладке.

Пример кода не могу скинуть, т.к. вообще не понимаю, что это может быть. Но это не та популярная проблема, что показывает гугл - "отключение автоматического обновления страниц в хроме", это что-то другое.

На других браузерах такого нет

Comment: Какой вес у сайта, сколько элементов подгружается? Посмотрите в веб-консоле в разделе сеть и скиньте скриншоты. Еще вариант может быть с неверной кодировкой. В плане UTF-8 c BOM

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть через дебаггер меняется ли что-нибудь в html страницы при фокусе.